# js functions placed in an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I've seen functions embedded in a structure and like to know if this is good practice. I enclose a piece of Java script to illustrate this. The numbers refer to the code flow. It seems rather diffucult to follow the flow.
Thanks

```js
anObject = {}; // an empty object
anObject.theGuts = (function() {
  console.log('In anObject.theGuts'); // #1
  theGuts = function(n) {
    this.n = n;
    console.log('theGuts called with:');
    console.log(this.n); // #6
  }
  return theGuts;
})();

anObject.theGame = (function() {
  function theGameGuts() {
    console.log('In theGameGuts'); // #4
    this.initGame();
  }
  var p = theGameGuts.prototype;
  p.initGame = function() {
    console.log('in initGame'); // #5
    anObject.theGuts(2);
  }
  return theGameGuts;
})()

console.log('the anObject');
console.log(anObject); // #2

window.onload = function() {
  console.log('In window.onload'); //#3
  // entry point
  var game = new anObject.theGame();
  console.log('the game: ');
  console.log(game); // #7
};
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>An edmbed test</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {

    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>Some text
  <script type="text/javascript" src='javaScript.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: JavaScript is flexible. There are many very different ways to structure code and just as many opinions as to which are a "good practice" and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

> I've seen functions embedded in a structure and like to know if this is good practice

Yes. Structuring code (in this case, placing functions on a "namespace") is always a good idea.

Using the *(revealing) module pattern* is also usually a good idea, although it might be a bit over-used here - instead of using one IIFE per property, one might have used a single, larger one for the whole `anObject`. Depends on how closely related the parts are to each other in the real code.

---

Some specific points for improvement, though:

> ```
> anObject.theGuts = (function() {
>   … theGuts
> })();
> ```

This IIFE seems to be rather pointless, as it doesn't set up any local variables. Also, as `theGuts` is a method of the `anObject` object, it better should have been assigned directly on it - and when a closure is required, it should wrap the whole object declaration.

> ```
>   console.log('In anObject.theGuts'); // #1
> ```

Not sure whether this adds a lot to your confusion of code flow, but IIFEs best don't have any side effects (including no logging).

> ```
>   theGuts = function(n) {
> ```

You're [missing a `var`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) here!

> ```
>     this.n = n;
> ```

Your method is *creating* a property here? It would have been better if this was "declared" at the object itself before.

> ```
>   function theGameGuts() {
> ```

A constructor's name should be capitalized: `TheGameGuts`.

> ```
>     this.initGame();
>   }
>   theGameGuts.prototype.initGame = function() {
>     …
>   }
> ```

Except you plan to call `.initGame()` separately, the *initialisation* of an instance should be done directly in the constructor itself. Do not use `init` methods - they only mess up your code flow.